# angular 2 : this._Router.navigate(['/app/home']); works but, previous page is still on the home page

Tags: angular, routes, navigation

I can navigate properly with `this._Router.navigate(['/app/home']);` syntax.
But, it keeps the previous page data on home page.

Comment: Am not understand what you are asking. can you explain it more? And guys don't answer unless you are not understand the question.

Comment: I am navigate my page one to another page but it displays both pages if suppose i have 2 components ComponentA, ComponentB and respective template like (Html code) TemplateA and TemplateB, after i navigate from componentA to componentB templates are be like
 <templateB><templateA>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. for this routing use:

   ```
   this._Router.navigate(['/app', 'home']);
   ```
2. What does your html look like? Did you integrate the router outlet?

Comment: yes i integrate it, it redirects properly to that component but i can see previous html code also after navigate, means it appears two components UI